# Strange memory leak in Visual C++ 2012 Update 2

Tags: visual-c++

I don't known why the code below is produce memory leak

```cpp
XTL::CManagedInternetHandle hRemoteFile;
XTL::CUrlExPtr pFinalUrl;

if (dwServiceType == INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP)
{
    throw CWindowsInternetException(url, E_FAIL, L"Unable to get final URL.");
```

But, when I move the throw to above, Like this

```cpp
XTL::CManagedInternetHandle hRemoteFile;
XTL::CUrlExPtr pFinalUrl;

throw CWindowsInternetException(url, E_FAIL, L"Unable to get final URL.");

if (dwServiceType == INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP)
{
```

no memory leak occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The memory leak is occurred in the method caller. I still don't known why memory leak report work only on the first code. It should work on both. Maybe it is a bug of VC++.